# Draw custom shape on canvas in android using path

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, shapes

I am trying to draw a shape (shape1) on canvas using path class but not able to draw it.However i am able to make a shape (shape2) using pathclass [image: Shape]

code for shape2(Dotted) is given below

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int h = getMeasuredHeight();
    int w = getMeasuredWidth();

    int value = (w/2)-90;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(value, 0);
    path.lineTo(value + 120, h);
    path.moveTo(value + 120, h);
    path.lineTo(-W, h);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, bgPaint);

}
```

I am unable to manoeuvre above code to achieve shape1

Comment: Have you stepped through your code and tried to understand each call?

Comment: Yup, (0,0) is initial point,From here it goes horizontally to (value,0),Then it translate vertically and horizontally to (value+120,h),After that is moves horizontally backwards to (-w,h) and path is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be something like

```
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(value, 0);
path.lineTo(value + delta, h);
path.lineTo(delta, h);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
```

where delta is 120 in your case

Comment: Ahhh, Silly me.Thanks mate

Comment: First line doesn't do anything since 0,0 is the default origin already.
Last line could be path.close() as the close method draw a line from last point to origin.